# ¿Cómo convertir dato de tipo string de un asp:TextBox a DATE de SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Que tal, tengo una exception al enviar los datos de mi formulario (webforms)
a una db en sqlserver.
estoy utilizando un textbox con datapicker de bootstrap y al enviarlo a la validacion en c# me genera error por el tipo de dato, como convertir dato de text a DATE?

```
           <div class="form-group">
                <div id="date2">
                    <label for="DateTextbox" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Created Date</label>
                    <div class='input-group col-sm-10 date' id="Created_date_picker">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextbox" name="expirationday" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Created Date" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="TextBox2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Calification Clasification</label>
                <div class='col-sm-10'>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" name="title" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Calification" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </div>
            </div>


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tabla (CREATED_DATE,CALIFICATION_1)VALUES(@CREATED_DATE,@CALIFICATION_1;", con);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CREATED_DATE", SqlDbType.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CALIFICATION_1", SqlDbType.Int);

        //asignamos el valor de los textbox a los parametros

        cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = DateTextbox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@CALIFICATION_1"].Value = TextBox2.Text;


        //abrimos conexion
        con.Open();
        //ejecutamos la instruccion con ExcecuteNonQuerry indicando que no retorna registros.
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //cerramos conexion
        con.Close();
```

cabe mencionar que la columna de la tabla CREATED_DATE es de tipo date.

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar esto:

```
cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = DateTextbox;
```

...a algo asi o semejante:

```
cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = DateTextbox.Date;
```

Si aun parece mal, trato de cambiar con algo como:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = DateTextbox.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

### ACTUALIZAR

Si DateTextbox esta un Textbox y no un DateTimePicker, puedes usar:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = DateTextbox.Text.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

...y despues:

```
cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = sqlFormattedDate;
```

Comment: me dice que textbox no tiene una definicion para date,
ya lo busque en 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx
Y EFECTIVAMENTE TEXTBOX NO TIENE NINGUNA PROPIEDAD DATE,
me pregunto si deberia cambiar el control textbox por algun otro?

Comment: Lo siento; creo que DateTextBox fue un DateTimePicker. Puedes usar "string sqlFormattedDate = DateTextbox.Text.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");" y despues "cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = sqlFormattedDate;"

Comment: me genera error tipo system.format.exception

Comment: Que esta en DateTextbox.Text?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

string date = DateTextbox.Text;
DateTime convertir = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

Solo agregas la variable convertir a tus parámetros.
Espero te sirva saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

string date = DateTextbox.Text; DateTime convertir = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

Solo agregas la variable convertir a tus parámetros. 
Espero te sirva saludos.

Answer (score 0):

_./

Tu código es el siguiente:

```
cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = DateTextbox.Date;
```

Podrías realizar lo siguiente:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.parse(DatetTextbox.Text);
cmd.Parameters["@CREATED_DATE"].Value = d.Date;
```

Espero te funcione.

¡Mucha Suerte! :D